# Can class fields be sealed?

Tags: c#, oop, field, sealed

In the [MSDN C# programming guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173150.aspx), it is mentioned that:

> "A class member, method, **field**, property, or event, on a derived class that is overriding a virtual member of the base class can declare that member as sealed."

I understand the above statement for methods, properties and events, but how is the above statement valid for fields of a class? I tried this in a program and verified that a field cannot be virtual and hence cannot be overridden. So how can it be sealed then? And if it cannot, should the above statement from the MSDN reference have left out mention of field?

Thanks.

Comment: Even Jon Skeet needs a weekend off!

Comment: @UweKeim do not worry I am here! :-D And I have almost read half of Skeet's book.

Comment: That's an error. I'll mention it to the documentation manager.

Comment: I've informed the documentation manager. Also, that "class member" in there is redundant and confusing. And indexers are not on the list! The sentence should properly read *A method, indexer, property, or event on a derived class that is overriding a virtual member of the base class can declare that member as sealed.*

Comment: Now, we need a [meta-tag:status-planned] tag

Comment: @ Eric: Thanks for pointing out the missing mention of indexers also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is indeed an error on that page.

The `sealed` keyword is not applicable to fields.

Answer (score 5):

The sealed keyword is not applicable to fields, according to the [C# Language Specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/D/0BDA894F-2CCD-4C2C-B5A7-4EB1171962E5/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.docx)

- docx document http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/D/0BDA894F-2CCD-4C2C-B5A7-4EB1171962E5/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.docx
- download page http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029

In particular notice the grammar reference in Appendix C